# wxpython gauge styles and pulse

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Ive written some wxpython code to display a progress bar/gauge.  Ive noticed that if i run my code by itself, i can simply call self.gauge.Pulse() one time  (with no timer running) and the gauge will pulse/move in a green bar.

However, when running my code as part of a larger body of code, the bar becomes a solid blue color and self.gauge.Pulse() does not pulse the bar.  Just stays constant.

The larger body of code does contain other wxFrames.

Is there some kind of frame style flag or something else that would disable the "auto pulse" feature and turn the bar from green to blue?

this is windows 7, btw

thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your "larger body of code" is not using the correct manifest and so uses the old, "classic" controls instead of the "themed" controls implemented by comctl32.dll v6. To check this easily, just compare the look of the buttons in the 2 cases, this should make it clear whether you use the correct manifest or not.

Comment: Both pieces of code are being run on the same machine, with the same python installation.  No version control is in effect (ie use version x or y of any modules).  Are you suggesting the difference is in the wxpython Style flags? How would i specify classic vs themed controls?

Comment: Manifest is defined at the application level and, usually, outside of the code, this is not about style flags.

Comment: Ok, Ive come back to this.  Do you have an example of how to define/specify the manifest to use?